# Where do I get my tf_server_identity_account_id?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Where do you find or get your tf_server_identity_account_id in Team Fortress 2? I need it not to complete achievements, but to remove the error that said invalid account id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by changing the tf_server_account_id to default.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `tf_server_identity_account_id` (along with the `tf_server_identity_token`) from your Team Fortress 2 Client (Game). Just open the game on your local computer and follow the steps below.

To clarify, this is only needed if you're running a TF2 Server.

**From the [Steam Knowledge Base](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2825-AFGJ-3513):**

- Sign onto Steam using the user account that you want to associate the server(s) with.
- Launch the Team Fortress 2 client.
- Execute the console command: `cl_gameserver_create_identity`
- You should see output in your console similar to this:

```
    ] cl_gameserver_create_identity
    Request to retrieve owned game server accounts--please wait. 
    Game server account created successfully!
    Set these convars on your game server to have it log in and receive benefits:     
    tf_server_identity_account_id nnnnnn
    tf_server_identity_token "xxxxx"
```

- Take the last two lines and paste them into your `\tf\cfg\server.cfg config` file.